# Glitches after closing/opening laptop lid. T410p, NVIDIA

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo T440p. I have an integrated Intel GPU, which works fine (until now), and another gpu (NVIDIA GeForce 730M) which I wanted to use instead. I installed the drivers but I had the following problem: whenever I close the lid the laptop goes into sleep mode, but when I open the lid, the screen shows crap (it's not black, it has glitches) and it doesn't return normal. It's kind of annoying since one has to shut down the computer brutally.
I also tried installing directly the drivers which one can download from the NVIDIA website, or doing everything on Ubuntu 13.10 but this doesn't change much.

Note that this only happens when I'm using the NVIDIA gpu. If I deactivate the driver for the NVIDIA, and use the intel instead, then the screen works fine, also after having reopened the lid after sleep mode.
With Ubuntu 13.10 it's the same. I have read in some forums that some other users had the problem that they're screen went black after sleep mode, but I couldn't find any post about glitches, and I also tried the solutions for the black screen.

If there is a similar post, please delete this one, if not, I'd be happy to hear from someone that had the same problem or that has a clue about it!
thanks,
nico

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with NVIDIA 740M, from what I have read so far its seems to be related to the NVIDIA prime tecnology that allows to switch between the INTEL and NVIDA GPUs on the fly. The only work around for the hard power off is Ctrl + ALt + f1 follow by a Ctrl + Alt + F7 that will show you the login dialog box. Some of the apps like browser it will show like crap so you will need to restart.

Please let me know if you find a solution. I think I have read about someone that made it to fully disable the Prime feature.

Julian

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately it appears to be a hardware problem. I guess lenovo geniuses didn't think of this or at least did not think to advise people about this issue

Comment: Hi Julian?
did you find any solution to that problem?